# Why is this implicit binding not being picked up by the Scala compiler?

Tags: scala, implicit

I've set up an implicit binding below, with an expectation that the *TweetProvider*  trait will be bound to *FancyRestaraunt* (i.e. a toy app for simulating a twitter feed, where people generate tweets after they eat at a fancy restaraunt).

However, it seems that the implicit binding which I created isn't getting utilized.

Any thoughts on how this implementation is incorrect ?

```
import scala.Product
import scala.io.BytePickle.PU
import scala.tools.cmd.ParserUtil

trait TweetProvider[Prod] {
  def getTweet(a:Prod): String;
}

class FancyRestaurant {
  def name(){
    "Fancy Restaurant"
  }
}

class RestaurantTweetosphere {

  def getTweet[Prod]
    (prod : Prod)
    (implicit product : TweetProvider[Prod])
        = product.getTweet(prod);

  implicit val FancyRestaurantTweet = new TweetProvider[FancyRestaurant]{
    def getTweet(r : FancyRestaurant) = {
      "OMG I love this "+r.name();
    }
  }

  def run() = {
    val c = new FancyRestaurant;
    c.getTweet() // <-- doesnt compile

  }

}
```

Comment: Is there an implementation for `getTweet` in `FancyRestaurant` that you haven't posted here?

Comment: This program is attempting to bind FancyRestaraunt to the TweetProvider type class.  So, I'm intentionally excluding an implementation of getTweet inside of FancyRestaurant, because I want to inherit that functionality from the implicit.  I've (1) declared the type class (TweetProvider) (2) create an instance binding (FancyRestaurantTweet) .... But scala's compiler doesn't seem to be glueing the two together in the way that I believe it is supposed to.

Comment: You want `getTweet(c)`, not `c.getTweet()`. With that change it compiles.